# SameSite cookies IIS

Tags: iis

I have tried samesite cookies in IIS. But no luck. how can I do that using in IIS ? BTW , I am using windows server 2012 R2.

config :

```
<sessionState timeout="60" cookieSameSite="None" />
<httpCookies sameSite="None"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is often managed within the application's startup and initialization.

One way to do this in IIS, rather than your application, is to add an outbound rewrite rule to append `SameSite=None` to cookies sent in the response.

Example `Web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None" />
      </rule>
      <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="No SameSite">
          <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
          <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
      </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MSFT documents:

The behavior of None was modified by updates described in KB article 4531182 and KB article 4524421.

Without these updates, the None value does not emit the SameSite cookie header

I suggest you could firstly install the KB article 4531182 and KB article 4524421 update and then it will work well.

More details, you could refer to below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.samesitemode?view=netframework-4.8#remarks