# Cookie is not getting updated in IIS hosted ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

In our ASP.NET MVC app hosted on IIS, we are facing an issue where the cookie is not getting overwritten when the user switches culture.

However, interestingly, when we debug the app using IIS Express, the cookie works fine.

We're curious about the possible reasons behind this discrepancy. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is for security reasons. Browsers are also strict about the update management of cookies.

You can refer to [The ultimate guide to secure cookies with web.config in .NET](https://blog.elmah.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-secure-cookies-with-web-config-in-net/). Incorporating the rewrite rule.

**Work with SameSite cookies in ASP.NET** official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite. Related cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60087566/20058276.